# Video (from SD card) thumbnail does not show in ImageView - Android

Tags: android, video, bitmap, android-adapter, android-sdcard

I think I have most of my code right. I'm trying to take videos (Uri) from my SD card, change them to bitmaps and put it through `ThumbnailUtils` (as suggested here on Stack), like this:

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(singleFile);
// create thumbnail: MINI_KIND: 512 x 384 thumbnail
bitmapThumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(uri.getPath(),MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
```

This code seems to be correct. Where it gets complicated is that I'm using a model and an adapter, so go through a few steps.

1. Pull the videos from my SD card
2. Change the `Uri` into a `Bitmap` for the `ThumbnailUtils` method.
3. Put that bitmap into a new `VideoGridItem` object
4. Add that object to my adapter.
5. Call `getVideo()` in my adapter class which gets the bitmap from my model object
6. Set that bitmap to my `ImageView` in my adapter

There might be something I'm missing in these steps. I did a log on this: `Bitmap bm = videoGridItem.getVideo();` and oddly, `bm` returns null. Which makes sense since I see nothing in the place where my video should be.

The screenshot below, shows that the code did pull my 1 video from my SD card (so my file I/O is probably okay) and filled the rest of the grid with placeholder images, but I'm don't know why it's not showing the video thumbnail. There is no crash or anything, just no thumbnail. Thanks for your help.

[image]

**VideoTab.java**

```
package org.azurespot.cutecollection.videotab;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.ThumbnailUtils;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;

import org.azurespot.R;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by mizu on 2/8/15.
 */
public class VideoTab extends Fragment {


    ArrayList<VideoGridItem> videoList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayAdapter<VideoGridItem> adapter;
    private String[] numberSDCardFiles = null;
    File[] files;
    Bitmap bitmapThumb;
    VideoGridItem videoGridItem;
    VideoGridItem drawableObject;


    public VideoTab() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_tab, container, false);

        // Create the Custom Adapter Object
        adapter = new GridViewVideoAdapter(getActivity(), videoList);
        // with fragments, make sure you include the rootView when finding id
        GridView gridView = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.video_grid);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

        if(adapter.getCount() == 0) {
            // load contents of SD card
            loadVideos();

            // turn drawable into an object of type Bitmap
            drawableObject = new VideoGridItem(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.ic_video_placeholder));

            // add the default icons remaining, to GridView, if less than 14 files on SD card
            for (int i = 0; i < (14 - numberSDCardFiles.length); i++) {
                adapter.add(drawableObject);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }


        return v;
    }

    public void loadVideos() {

        try {

            // gets directory Cute Videos from sd card
            File cuteVideosDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory
                    (Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES), "Cute Videos");

            files = cuteVideosDir.listFiles();

            for (File singleFile : files) {

                Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(singleFile);

                // create thumbnail: MINI_KIND: 512 x 384 thumbnail
                bitmapThumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(uri.getPath(),
                        MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);

                videoGridItem = new VideoGridItem(bitmapThumb);

                Log.d("TAG", "Value of videoGridItem: " + videoGridItem);

                adapter.add(videoGridItem);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // get number of files in Cute Videos directory
        numberSDCardFiles =  new String[files.length];
    }
}
```

**GridViewVideoAdapter.java**

```
package org.azurespot.cutecollection.videotab;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import org.azurespot.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by mizu on 2/8/15.
 */
public class GridViewVideoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<VideoGridItem> {

    ViewHolder holder = null;
    int position;


    public GridViewVideoAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<VideoGridItem> videos) {
        super(context, 0, videos);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;
        this.position = position;

        if (v == null) {

            v = LayoutInflater.from(getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.video_grid_item, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.video_grid_view);
            // stores holder with view
            v.setTag(holder);

        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder)v.getTag();
        }

        // gets position of whichever photo you click on in the GridView
        final VideoGridItem videoGridItem = getItem(position);

        if (videoGridItem != null) {

            Bitmap bm = videoGridItem.getVideo();
            Log.d("TAG", "Value of bm: " + bm);

            holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);

            // positioning the image in the GridView slot
            holder.imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(512, 384));
        }

        return v;

    }

    public class ViewHolder{
        ImageView imageView;
    }
}
```

**VideoGridItem.java**

```
package org.azurespot.cutecollection.videotab;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;

/**
 * Created by mizu on 3/28/15.
 */
public class VideoGridItem {

    private Bitmap video;


    public VideoGridItem(Bitmap video) {
        super();
        this.video = video;

    }

    public Bitmap getVideo() {

        return video;
    }


    public void setVideo(Bitmap video) {
        this.video = video;
    }
}
```

Comment: Down vote with no comment is unhelpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my video saving code (in another activity) was not correct after all. I did not think it had any errors, because videos were getting saved to my SD card just fine. But what I didn't realize is that they were not playable. Upon closer look, I saw that only an assigned file name was being saved, not the actual `Uri` of the video.

So what other posts said about `ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail()` was indeed correct: the only time it will return `null` is if the video file is corrupt or inoperable. So once I fixed that, everything worked like a charm. So the above code is actually working code.

Lesson learned: don't assume you have a working video in your SD card directory! Even if it is in sheep's clothing (the mp4 files really looked perfectly fine), it might be a wolf underneath.

Comment: lol `Even if it is in sheep's clothing (the mp4 files really looked perfectly fine), it might be a wolf underneath.` +1 me have the same case